# Get the change in price for all most recent prices in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-function

I've been tasked with writing an application that will allow the user to search a table of prices, where prices are unique on 3 different keys, say **state**, **publisher**, and **type** (there may be any number of rows with the same key value for any of the 3 fields, but there is only one row with **state**='Ohio', **publisher**='Bob', and **type**='silicon'). When a user selects the **state** and **publisher**, they are presented a list of all of the **types** with that **state** and **publisher**. I run a stored procedure to pull these items, and I am pulling the most recent price, but I also need to pull the second most recent price and do math to get the change in price to display to the user. currently, I created the following function, but it slows down my stored procedure by anywhere from 1 to 40 seconds, depending on the mood of the server when executed.

```
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @priceChange float
    DECLARE @currentPriceDate date
    DECLARE @currentPrice float
    DECLARE @previousPrice float

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    SELECT TOP 1 @currentPriceDate=PriceDate ,@CurrentPrice=MarketPrice
        FROM MarketPrice_Table
            LEFT JOIN PriceEffectiveDate_Table ON MarketPrice_Table.PriceDate = PriceEffectiveDate_Table.EffectiveDate
                AND MarketPrice_Table.PublisherID = PriceEffectiveDate_Table.PublisherID
        WHERE TypeID = @TypeID
        AND MarketPrice_Table.PublisherID = @PublisherID
        AND MarketPrice_Table.StateID = @StateID
        ORDER BY PriceDate DESC;

    SET @previousPrice = (SELECT TOP 1 MarketPrice 
        FROM MarketPrice_Table
            LEFT JOIN PriceEffectiveDate_Table ON MarketPrice_Table.PriceDate = PriceEffectiveDate_Table.EffectiveDate
                AND MarketPrice_Table.PublisherID = PriceEffectiveDate_Table.PublisherID
        WHERE TypeID = @TypeID
        AND MarketPrice_Table.PublisherID = @PublisherID
        AND MarketPrice_Table.StateID = @StateID
        AND MarketPrice_Table.PriceDate <> @currentPriceDate
        ORDER BY PriceDate DESC);

    SET @priceChange = @currentPrice - @previousPrice;

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @priceChange

END
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this so I am not making two queries per row in the stored procedure?

Thank you in advance for any help, and let me know if I can clarify anything further!

Comment: First I recommend you convert date to string Convert(varchar,MarketPrice_Table.PriceDate,112) <> Convert(varchar,@currentPriceDate,112)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the LEAD analytically function and use it return the data in a table.  I apologize if this not exact but with some modification i'm sure it will give you what you're looking for.

Try:

```
DECLARE @priceChange float
DECLARE @currentPriceDate date
DECLARE @currentPrice float
DECLARE @previousPrice FLOAT

SELECT
    *
FROM
    (   
        SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MarketPrice_Table.StateID, MarketPrice_Table.PublisherID, TypeID ORDER BY PriceDate DESC) AS RowNum,
            MarketPrice_Table.StateID,
            MarketPrice_Table.PublisherID,
            TypeID,
            PriceDate, 
            MarketPrice AS CurrentPrice,
            LEAD(MarketPrice) OVER (PARTITION BY MarketPrice_Table.StateID, MarketPrice_Table.PublisherID, TypeID ORDER BY PriceDate DESC) AS PreviousPrice,
            MarketPrice - ISNULL(LEAD(MarketPrice) OVER (PARTITION BY MarketPrice_Table.StateID, MarketPrice_Table.PublisherID, TypeID ORDER BY PriceDate DESC), 0) AS PriceChange
        FROM 
            MarketPrice_Table
            LEFT JOIN PriceEffectiveDate_Table 
                ON MarketPrice_Table.PriceDate = PriceEffectiveDate_Table.EffectiveDate
                AND MarketPrice_Table.PublisherID = PriceEffectiveDate_Table.PublisherID
        WHERE 
            TypeID = @TypeID AND 
            MarketPrice_Table.PublisherID = @PublisherID AND 
            MarketPrice_Table.StateID = @StateID
    ) r
WHERE
    r.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: I am currently implementing this method, and it seems to really be working quickly. It does not return the DIFFERENCE between the CurrentPrice and PreviousPrice though, so I'm trying to figure out how to get that out of it. I will accept it as the answer if I can get this working. Thank you very much!

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you! Before I read your reply I changed the `Select *` to `Select CurrentPrice-PreviousPrice`, which also heeded the result I was after. But after looking at execution times, your version is faster. Thank you again! I'd been scratching my head over this all day!

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

```
BEGIN
-- Declare the return variable here
DECLARE @priceChange float
DECLARE @currentPriceDate varchar(8)
DECLARE @currentPrice float
DECLARE @previousPrice float

-- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
SELECT TOP 1 @currentPriceDate=Convert(varchar,PriceDate,112) ,@CurrentPrice=MarketPrice
    FROM MarketPrice_Table
        LEFT JOIN PriceEffectiveDate_Table ON Convert(varchar,MarketPrice_Table.PriceDate,112) = Convert(varchar,PriceEffectiveDate_Table.EffectiveDate,112)
            AND MarketPrice_Table.PublisherID = PriceEffectiveDate_Table.PublisherID
    WHERE TypeID = @TypeID
    AND MarketPrice_Table.PublisherID = @PublisherID
    AND MarketPrice_Table.StateID = @StateID
    ORDER BY PriceDate DESC;

SET @previousPrice = (SELECT TOP 1 MarketPrice 
    FROM MarketPrice_Table
        LEFT JOIN PriceEffectiveDate_Table ON Convert(varchar,MarketPrice_Table.PriceDate,112) = Convert(varchar,PriceEffectiveDate_Table.EffectiveDate)
            AND MarketPrice_Table.PublisherID = PriceEffectiveDate_Table.PublisherID
    WHERE TypeID = @TypeID
    AND MarketPrice_Table.PublisherID = @PublisherID
    AND MarketPrice_Table.StateID = @StateID
    AND Convert(varchar,MarketPrice_Table.PriceDate,112) <> @currentPriceDate
    ORDER BY PriceDate DESC);

SET @priceChange = @currentPrice - @previousPrice;

-- Return the result of the function
RETURN @priceChange

END
```